# PyQt6 Installation failed on building dependencies

Tags: python, pip, pyqt, pyqt6

I am trying to install PyQt6 with pip. But it could not succeed.I am using python 3.9.0 32 bit in Windows 8.1.

I tried PyQt5 installation ,it works fine.
I think there is something error with **building dependencies** and some metadata generation process.
Is there any unofficial wheel for PyQt6?
Can anyone help me out?

**Here is the Error:**

```
C:\Users\Rajkumar\Desktop>pip install PyQt6
Collecting PyQt6
  Using cached PyQt6-6.2.3.tar.gz (1.0 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  x Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ?─> [29 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "e:\python\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_proc
ess.py", line 156, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          hook = backend.prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
      AttributeError: module 'sipbuild.api' has no attribute 'prepare_metadata_f
or_build_wheel'

      During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "e:\python\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_proc
ess.py", line 363, in <module>
          main()
        File "e:\python\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_proc
ess.py", line 345, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "e:\python\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_proc
ess.py", line 160, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          whl_basename = backend.build_wheel(metadata_directory, config_settings
)
        File "C:\Users\Rajkumar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-ws9aovo_\overla
y\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\api.py", line 51, in build_wheel
          project = AbstractProject.bootstrap('pep517')
        File "C:\Users\Rajkumar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-ws9aovo_\overla
y\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\abstract_project.py", line 83, in bootstrap
          project.setup(pyproject, tool, tool_description)
        File "C:\Users\Rajkumar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-ws9aovo_\overla
y\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\project.py", line 594, in setup
          self.apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "project.py", line 67, in apply_user_defaults
          super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "C:\Users\Rajkumar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-ws9aovo_\overla
y\Lib\site-packages\pyqtbuild\project.py", line 70, in apply_user_defaults
          super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "C:\Users\Rajkumar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-ws9aovo_\overla
y\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\project.py", line 241, in apply_user_defaults
          self.builder.apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "C:\Users\Rajkumar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-ws9aovo_\overla
y\Lib\site-packages\pyqtbuild\builder.py", line 67, in apply_user_defaults
          raise PyProjectOptionException('qmake',
      sipbuild.pyproject.PyProjectOptionException
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem wit
h pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

x Encountered error while generating package metadata.
?─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

C:\Users\Rajkumar\Desktop>
```

Comment: It doesn't need to be compiled (it's a lot of unnecessary work), just use 64-bit python and not the one you have installed since it's 32-bit.

Comment: But my pc is 32 bit. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: The long way is to install all the dependencies that for example is Qt, I doubt that there are 32-bit binaries so you will have to compile it (which is heavy if you don't know c++) and I don't know if it has 32-bit support either (I think that no). So good luck.

Comment: if i use 64 bit python then will my application developed through PyQt run on 32 bit windows?

Comment: No, 32-bit binaries can run on 64-bit devices but not vice versa.

Comment: Ok.then i have to adjust with PyQt5. Actually there is nothing problem with pyqt5 ,the only problem i am facing is using my appliaction in **HighDPI** screen.I tried every method but only  `QApplication.setAttribute(Qt.HighDpiScaleFactorRoundingPolicy.PassThrough)` works but it gives a **Faded look (Faded Font)** to my GUI. Do you know what line can fix the pronlem? I mean first what line,then what line i need to write? As they mentioned in PyQt6 default option is **PassThrough**,I thought they fixed  that problem. Thank you! This is the the only problem with pyqt5.